# Difference between eigenvalues of the potential energy Hessian vs. "generalized" eigenvalues with respect to a kinetic energy "metric"

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, kinematics

**Simple version**

Consider if we have a Lagrangian defined by
$$L(q,\dot{q}) = \frac{1}{2} g_{ij}(q) \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j - U(q) \tag{1a}$$
where the potential energy $U(q)$ has a single minimum at $q=0$ ($q$ here is a collection of coordinates). We are interested in studying the harmonic fluctuations about the minimum. Define the Hessian matrix as
$$U(q) = U_0 + \frac{1}{2} Q_{ij} q^i q^j + \mathcal{O}(q^3) \qquad, \qquad Q_{ij} = \left.\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial {q}^i \partial {q}^j}\right|_{q=0}\tag{2a}$$
The Euler Lagrange equations for the harmonic fluctuations are then
$$g_{ij}(0)\ddot{q}^j = -Q_{ij} q^j\tag{3a}$$
The general solutions are of the form
$$q(t) = \sum_n A_n \sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}\,t) \psi_n\tag{4a}$$
where
$$Q\psi_n = \lambda_n g\psi_n \tag{5a}$$
that is, $\psi_n$ is a generalized eigenvector of $Q$ with respect to the "metric" $g$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_n$. We recognize then that the generalized eigenvalues arising from the EOM $\lambda_n$ are the squared frequencies of normal mode oscillations.

**Question**

> We now have two notions of the eigenvalues of the Hessian. One is the plain eigenvalues which are positive definite, solutions of $\mathrm{det}(Q-\lambda I) = 0$. The other are the generalized eigenvalues with respect to the "kinetic energy metric" $g$, solutions of $\mathrm{det}(Q-\lambda' g)=0$. The latter appear to have the meaning of (squared) frequencies of normal modes, what do the former represent? What about the respective eigenvectors? (In a quantum version of this problem, both sets of eigenvalues can be thought of as defining energies or frequencies via $\hbar$).

**A more specific version of the same problem**

This question arose in the context of spin waves. Consider a generalized Heisenberg Hamiltonian for the spins
$$H = \sum_{ij}\sum_{\alpha\beta} S_i^\alpha J_{ij}^{\alpha\beta} S_j^\beta$$
where $i,j$ label lattice sites and $\alpha,\beta$ label spin components. Note that $H$ is precisely what would appear in the partition function if I wanted to compute equal-time correlation functions, $Z = \mathrm{Tr}(e^{-\beta H})$.

At low temperature let's assume for simplicity that we have a ferromagnetic ground state where all the spins align along one direction which we call $\hat{z}$. We expand the spin vector as $\mathbf{S} = (S_x,S_y,\sqrt{1-S_x^2 + S_y^2}) \approx (S_x,S_y,1-(S_x^2+S_y^2)/2)$ and expand the Hamiltonian to quadratic order in the spin deviations
$$H = E_0 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}\sum_{ab} S_i^a Q_{ij}^{ab} S_j^b + \mathcal{O}(S^3) \tag{2b} $$
where $E_0$ is the ground state energy, $Q$ is the Hessian, and $a,b$ label the $x,y$ spin components. Here the Hessian clearly has a relation to the *energies* of the normal modes.

Define a vector $z = (S_1^x, S_1^y, S_2^x, S_2^y, \cdots)$. The equation of motion $d\mathbf{S}_i/dt = \mathbf{S}_i \times \mathbf{H}_{\mathrm{eff}}$ is derived from a Lagrangian of the form
$$L = \frac{1}{2} z^T \Gamma \frac{d}{dt}z - U(z) \approx \frac{1}{2} z^T \Gamma \frac{d}{dt}z - \frac{1}{2} z^T Q z\tag{1b}$$
where the potential energy $U$ is equivalent to the Hamiltonian above, $H$, and the matrix $\Gamma$ is block-diagonal of the form
$$\Gamma_{ii}^{ab} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
The equation of motion is
$$\Gamma \frac{d}{dt} z = Q z\tag{3b}$$
whose general solution is of the form
$$z(t) = \sum_n c_n e^{-i\omega_n t} \psi_n\tag{4b}$$
such that
$$(i\omega_n \Gamma + Q)\psi_n = 0\tag{5b}$$
Clearly here $\omega_n$ are once again the frequencies of the travelling spin wave eigenmodes.

**Restatement of question**

> What is the relationship between the eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) of the Hessian $Q$, which are positive definite and have dimensions of energy, and the generalized eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) of $Q$ with respect to the "kinetic energy metric" $i\Gamma$, which in this case come in pairs $\omega_{-n} = - \omega_n$? (The quantum version of this problem is quantum spin waves, in which the $\omega_n$ can be interpreted as energies, $\hbar\omega_n$)

I feel like I am misunderstanding something fundamental about the difference between Lagrangians and Hamiltonians, and to what extent the Hamiltonian I defined above for the spins is actually a Hamiltonian in the quantum mechanical sense, i.e. a generator of time evolution, because it appears that it does not in fact contain information about the kinetic energy and therefore has no corresponding EOM. Rather, it should be thought of simply as a potential energy functional.